# Pandoc, make PDF for printing purposes, links into footnotes

Tags: pdf, printing, markdown, pandoc

I have a markdown document which I would like to convert to a PDF.

I will then be printing this PDF onto paper.

I would like to know how to convert my markdown in a PDF so that there are no digital elements the user has to click on. Since the document will be printed and it will be impossible for readers to click on anything.

I would like it so anything the user has to click on is converted into a footnote, or some other visual indicator.

The two main offenders I have found are web links and section links.

I am using the `-V links-as-notes=true` option to make all web links into footnotes.

However section links (ex: `[section name](#section-name)`) are still digital elements which must be clicked.

I have tried looking into the options provided by the packages pandoc uses which pandoc allows users to customize. However I have not found any relevant options.

Comment: don't use links in your markdown, but use footnotes instead! https://pandoc.org/MANUAL.html#footnotes

Comment: What would you like the section link footnotes to look like? Should they show up as footnotes at all?